# robotino_drivers building errors

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I am building the robotino_drivers, I get the following error message. How can I fix this problem?

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common/actionlib
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:43 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common/actionlib/cmake/actionbuild.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:44 (genaction):
  Unknown CMake command "genaction".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29436/robotino_drivers-building-errors/) by [rmznrkn](https://answers.ros.org/users/1942/rmznrkn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robotino_drivers was an old stack is no longer supported. I would recommend you to try out the new [robotino](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robotino) stack. The new stack is based on the new [RobotinoAPI2](http://wiki.openrobotino.org/index.php?title=API2) which is more efficient and is packed with new features. The API2 is currently undergoing its final stages of development but you can already install it on your Robotino.

If you have more questions regarding the RobotinoAPI2 then please post them on the [openrobotino](http://forum.openrobotino.org/) forum.

---

Originally posted by [Hozefa Indorewala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1548/hozefa-indorewala/) with karma: 28 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0